# best practice of getting _id back from mongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

im using `mongo-scala-driver` in my project and when I insert a record I want to save its mongo `_id` value.

this is my method:

```
def myInsert(record: Record): Future[ObjectId] = {

    val doc = Document(write(operationRecord))

    myCollection.insertOne(doc).toFuture().map(_ => ???)

  }
```

Im not sure what would be the right way in the map to return the ObjectId...I want to return that Future of ObjectId that was created by mongo.

my Record case class looks like this:

```
case class Record(fname: String, lname: String, time: LocalDate)
```

what would be your suggestion?

Comment: ReactiveMongo is not mongo-scala-driver

Comment: @cchantep i know, what r u trying to say?

Comment: I'm trying to say that this was wrongly tagged as a reactivemongo question